# Camel Request + Reply based on Sequence ( Async )

Tags: apache-camel

I'm new to Camel and still trying to grasp the idea of it.

This is the step that I want to build :

1. My application need to send a request file ( REQ1.TXT ) from my
   application to a file EndPoint ( a shared folder )
2. Another server reads the file, and within 10 minutes (approximately) put a response file (RESP1.TXT)
3. My application move the RESP1.TXT to my endpoint and process the response file.

Is this achieveable using Camel's Async Request-Reply or should I create 2 Routes(like below)?

```
 context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder()
 {public void configure()
  { 
    from("file:/temp/input/?include=REQ*.*txt").to("file:/shared/output/");
    from("file:/shared/output/?include=RES*.*txt").delay(600000).to("file:/temp/input/");
 }});
```

If this achieveable using Request Reply, how to implement it?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this question. You are talking about multiple servers but mention the file endpoint, which usually handles local files. By what means of transport do you intend to communicate between the servers? What you have mentioned can be solved in a lot of ways.

Comment: We have a shared filesystem(folder) and both servers have access(read/write) to the filesystem. So I'm planning to use file endpoint. I already able to make this works using 2 routes, however I'm confused whether I should use Request Reply here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file component (and file systems in general) does not have any concept of "Request/Reply". What you have in your supplied route is probably the way you have most control over it.

For what it looks like, you don't have any dependency to process the response in the same state as the request and in that way, it's actually better to keep the both routs separate anyway (regardless of protocol).